# can cuda + thrust projects be splitted to more than 1 file

Tags: cuda, thrust

im building and project which uses both Thrust (cuda api) and openMP technologies.the main purpose of my program is to present an interface to calculate something , simultaneously speaking.
in order to do that i've decided to use the STRATEGY design pattern , which basically means that we need to define a base class with a virtual function , and then other classes to derive from that base class and implement the needed function.

my problem starts here :
1 . can my project has more than 1 .CU file?
2 . can CU files have decleration of classes?

```
  class foo 
        {
            int m_name;
            void doSomething();
        }
```

3. this one continues 2. , i've head that DEVICE kernels can not be declared inside classes and has to be done like this :

```
//header file
__DEVICE__ void kernel(int x, inty)
{.....
}

class a : foo
{
   void doSomething();
}

//cu file

void a::doSomething()
{
  kernel<<<1,1>>>......();
}
```

is it the right way?
4.last question is , we i use THRUST , must i use CU files as well?

Thanks , igal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use multiple `.cu` files in your project.
2. Yes, but there are restrictions. According to *CUDA_C_Programming_Guide* v.4.0, section 3.1.5:

   > The front end of the compiler processes CUDA source files according to C++ syntax rules. Full C++ is supported for the host code. However, only a subset of C++ is fully supported for the device code as described in Appendix D. As a consequence of the use of C++ syntax rules, void pointers (e.g., returned by malloc()) cannot be assigned to non-void pointers without a typecast.
3. You're ALMOST correct. You have to use `__global__` keyword when declaring your kernel.

   ```
   __global__ void kernel(int x, inty)
   {.....
   }
   ```
4. Well, yes. Actually your thrust-boosted device code should be compiled with `nvcc`. See `thrust` documentation for details.

In general, you will compile your programs like that:

```
    $ nvcc -c device.cu
    $ g++  -c host.cpp   -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
    $ nvcc device.o host.o
```

Alternatively, you can use g++ to perform final linking step.

```
    $ g++ tester device.o host.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

On Windows change the paths after `-I` and `-L`. Also, as far as I know, you have to use `cl` compiler (MS Visual Studio).

*Note 1:*
Watch out for x86/x64 compatibility: if you use 64-bit CUDA Toolkit, use also a 64-bit compiler. (check `-m32` and `-m64` options of `nvcc` also)

*Note 2:*
`device.cu` contains kernels and a function that invokes kernel(s). This function has to be annotated with `extern "C"`.
It can contain classes (limitations apply).
`host.cpp` contains pure C++ code with a `extern "C"` **declaration** of the function that is in `device.cu` (NOT kernel).

Comment: thanks for the reply , about the question regarding the C++ part , what about the H files? those that actually define my class ?

Comment: What do you mean about header files? What's your background in C++ programming?

Comment: i mean that if for example im trying to implement the STRATEGY design pattern , my class has to implement a virtual function inherited by another class , so first i gotta have a H file that declares the class and in the CU i need to implement it , dont i?

Comment: I don't see any problems with this. You can do as you've written.

Comment: well i tried it , but it resulted with many unsolved errors including with main().... i will post it right away as i get home .